# Pandas, itertuples and set values based on other rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to update a row's column based on the previous row's column's value.

Like the following

```
<code>
d = {'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col3': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
rows = df.itertuples()
prev = next(rows)  # Gets first row
for row in rows:  # Will start at second row
    print("Current index:",row)
    setattr(row, 'col3') = getattr(prev,'col1')
    prev = row
</code>
```

This throws the error, 'SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call'.  Guess I will have to use iloc or loc?

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is the expected output?

Comment: Looks like you might want a simple `df['col3'] = df['col1'].shift()`